# Save the ios app configuration in secure

Tags: ios, security, jailbreak

I am developing an iOS application. My app need to save the configuration and status data at local. e.g. the app is on Free mode or paid mode. If I put this information into a plist file, may it can be access in jailbreak iphone? If yes, where should I save it in secure? ( Note: for some special reason, I don't want encrypt the data in plist file). I am hear about iOS State Preservation and Restoration, does it help me save data in a secure memory?

Update: My app runs on ipad with iOS 4.3 +
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put this information into a plist file, may it be accessed on a jailbroken iPhone?

Yes, it may. Since a jailbroken phone has a completely open filesystem and a working root user account, users can do literally anything with your application: grab its secret data, crack it, reverse engineer it, modify it using MobileSubstrate, etc., etc. (**Don't you dare** popping up an "I don't run on jailbroken devices!" alert view though!)

> If yes, where should I save it in securely?

In short: you can't.

There's this [keychain thingy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) which is supposed to be secure, but it isn't secure at all on jailbroken devices. The full contents of the keychain can be easily dumped by this [simple tool](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper).

Answer (score 1):

One idea regarding placing the data in secure place. If your application has some was of authentication, you can use this information to encrypt/decrypt some data.

It's not 100% secure. If another processes got to your process memory, copy data from it then you are screwed. However, if some other app will just copy a file it will be useless (because they will need to get your authentication info first to decrypt it).